# Get calendarweek of an NSDate according ISO 8601

Tags: ios, nsdate, iso, nscalendar

is there a way to get calendarweek of an NSDate according ISO 8601.
I think:

```
Datecomponents *dateComponents = [cal components:(NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit ) fromDate: testDate ];
int calandarWeek =  [dateComponents weekOfYear];
```

uses a different algorithm.

ISO definition: CW1 is the first week in the year containing 4 day, CW start on Mondays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out.
It´s possible to configure the NSCalender:

```
[cal setFirstWeekday:2];            //week starts on Monday
[cal setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:4];  //first week in the year containing 4 day
```