# number of calendarweeks for year (ISO 8601 definition)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nscalendar

how can I calculate the number of calendarweeks in objective-C for a given year.

I tried:

```
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit inUnit: NSYearCalendarUnit forDate: [NSDate date]].length
```

but it returns 54.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think 54 is wrong?

Comment: because years have either 52 or 53 calendarweeks. 2012 has 52 calendarweeks.

Comment: That sounds like it depends on the definition of calendar weeks.  366 days is 52 weeks and 2 days.  If those 2 days are each on different logical weeks, that adds up to 54.  That is, if a week starts on Monday, 2012 definitely has 54 weeks.

Comment: ah I understand. To be more precise I want the number of calandarweeks as defined in ISO 8601.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit`, so you must use the corresponding larger unit which is `NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit`.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.firstWeekday = 2;
calendar.minimumDaysInFirstWeek = 4;
int n = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit inUnit:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit forDate: [NSDate date]].length;
NSLog(@"%d", n); // 52
```

Finally, note that both `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit` and `NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit` are iOS 5.0 and OS X 10.7 only.

**Edit**

As noted by @lnafziger, if you use a date that is in a calendar week from the previous year or next year such as 1/1/2016, this will calculate the number of weeks in that year (2015 in the example), and not the actual year of the date (2016 in the example). If this is not what you want, you can change the date like follows:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
components.month = 3;
date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: OK. But how to calculate the number of calendarweeks as defined in ISO 8601

Comment: works fine, tnx  -- Is it OK to set the forDate: parameter to any date in the corresponding year e.g. : NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];comp.year=year;comp.month=2;
NSDate *aDay =[cal dateFromComponents:comp];
  calendarWeekInYear = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit inUnit: NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit forDate:aDay].length;

Comment: This has two issues:  1) While it happens to be correct for 2012, it doesn't work for many other years (2015 would be the next incorrect one).  This can be fixed by adding the following two lines:  `[calendar setFirstWeekday:2];  [calendar setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:4];`  2) It will calculate the correct value for the PREVIOUS year if you pick a date prior to the "official" start of the year (for the 8601 calendar).  i.e. in 2013 the first week of the year starts on the 7th, and if you calculate for the date 1/5/2013 it will return the value for 2012 (the year that date belongs in).

Comment: Note that issue #2 may be desirable since 1/5/2013 is technically part of the 52nd week of 2012 but may be confusing if not properly documented.

Comment: @lnafziger - Ok, thanks. I've forgot to add these two lines (I've already seen that OP did use them in his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9656833/1207152)).

Answer (score 2):

After a significant amount of testing, here is a function which will return it for any year:

```
- (NSUInteger)iso8601WeeksForYear:(NSUInteger)year {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *firstThursdayOfYearComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [firstThursdayOfYearComponents setWeekday:5]; // Thursday
    [firstThursdayOfYearComponents setWeekdayOrdinal:1]; // The first Thursday of the month
    [firstThursdayOfYearComponents setMonth:1]; // January
    [firstThursdayOfYearComponents setYear:year];
    NSDate *firstThursday = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstThursdayOfYearComponents];

    NSDateComponents *lastDayOfYearComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [lastDayOfYearComponents setDay:31];
    [lastDayOfYearComponents setMonth:12];
    [lastDayOfYearComponents setYear:year];
    NSDate *lastDayOfYear = [calendar dateFromComponents:lastDayOfYearComponents];

    NSDateComponents *result = [calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:firstThursday toDate:lastDayOfYear options:0];

    return result.week + 1;
}
```

Basically, per the spec, the total number of weeks is the same as the total number of Thursday's in the year, which is what this calculates.

I have tested it for the entire 400 year cycle (starting in the year 0 and the year 2000) and all cases match the spec.

Comment: I had  [cal setFirstWeekday:2]; 
  [cal setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:4]; included which is the ISO definition and got 54. If I only include [cal setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:4], as you sugest, I get 53 but the correct number is 52 for 2012.

Comment: well, setFirstWeekday should be 5 (Thursday)

Comment: why 5 (Thursday)? The first weekday in ISO is 1 (Monday).

Comment: Well, I was thinking that because it counts Thursdays and mistakenly thought that it was the beginning of the week.  I've done some more research and posted the correct answer above.  Hope this helps!